# How to convert a PyArrow table to a in-memory csv

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I'm searching for a way to convert a PyArrow table to a csv in memory so that I can dump the csv object directly into a database. With [pyarrow.csv.write_csv()](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.write_csv.html) it is possible to create a csv file on disk, but is it somehow possible to create a csv object in memory? I have difficulties to understand the documentation. Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [Python io module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) to write to memory:

```py
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> from pyarrow import csv
>>> import io

# Create a Table
>>> t = pa.Table.from_arrays([[1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]], ["c1", "c2"])

# Write to memory
>>> buf = io.BytesIO()
>>> csv.write_csv(t, buf, csv.WriteOptions(include_header=True))
>>> buf.seek(0)
0

# Read from memory for demo purposes
>>> csv.read_csv(buf)
pyarrow.Table
c1: int64
c2: string
----
c1: [[1,2,3]]
c2: [["a","b","c"]]
```